# Force update shared volume in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My Docker file for UI image is as follows

```
FROM node:alpine as prodnode
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

and my Docker Compose manifest looks like below.

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - ui
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/prod.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static:/usr/share/nginx/html
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./backend:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
  ui:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      context: ./ui/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./ui:/app
      - static:/app/build
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password

volumes:
  static:
```

I am trying to build static content and copy the content between ui container to Nginx container. I use shared volume. Everything works fine as expected. But when I change contents of ui and build again, changes are not reflecting. I tried the following:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build 
docker-compose up
```

None of them is replacing the static content with the new build.

Only when I remove the static volume like below

```
docker volume rm skeleton_static
```

and then do

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It is changing the content now. How do I automatically replace the static contents on every `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose up --build`?

Answer (score 1):

Named volumes are presumed to hold user data in some format Docker can't understand; Docker *never* updates their content after they're originally created, and if you mount a volume over image content, the old content in the volume hides updated content in the image.  As such, I'd avoid named volumes here.

It looks like in the setup you show, the `ui` container doesn't actually do anything: its main container process is to build the application, and then it exits immediately.  A [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is a more appropriate approach here, and it will let you compile the application during the image build phase without declaring a do-nothing container or adding the complexity of named volumes.

```bash
# ui/Dockerfile

# First stage: build the application; note this is
# very similar to the existing Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine as prodnode
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"] # not CMD

# Second stage: nginx server serving that application
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=prodnode /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# use default CMD from the base image
```

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you don't need separate "build" and "serve" containers, these are now combined together.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    # no volumes:
  ui:
    build: ./ui
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    # no volumes:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
    volumes: # do persist database data
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

A similar problem will apply to the anonymous volume you've used for the backend service's `node_modules` directory, and it will ignore any changes to the `package.json` file.  Since all of the application's code and library dependencies are already included in the image, I've deleted the `volumes:` block that would overwrite those.